# "Classic ASP" search engine IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, search-engine

We just upgraded from IIS6 to IIS7 for our intranet site.  All of our ASP.NET and Classic ASP apps are now working except for the Search page (which is written in classic asp).

We get: "Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'"  when trying to register ixsso.Query.

I know that IIS7 does not use ixsso, so I turned on Windows Search Service.  How do I code a simple web search either in classic asp or asp.net to utilize Windows Search Service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "Indexing Service" feature under the "File Services" > "Windows Server 2003 File Services" role.

This installs the old indexing service that is compatible with your classic ASP search.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Other than installing the old Indexing Services on 2008, is there any other way?  Even if I rewrite the code to use the native IIS7 search?

Comment: @JackV there might be via SharePoint and I haven't looked into it for over a year (maybe 2) but it was far more difficult than indexing server and Classic ASP.